# How to add profile specific properties files when I have custom name to my property file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have properties file with name : **transactionexpiry.properties** in my project's src/main/resources folder.

I am able to read the properties in the code with @PropertySource("classpath:/transactionexpiry.properties")

Now I wan't to add application scope and add environment specific config files as **transactionexpiry-dev.properties, transactionexpiry-local.properties**, etc

But the same works with **application.properties, application-dev.properties, application-local.properties**

Is there a way to make it work with my previous set-up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using spring profiles:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

Then you can call the properties file like:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/transactionexpiry${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
```

Comment: And you are dead if you use more that 1 profile.